# Excel: Calculating values by date

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have collected a lot of data for different days. 
For each day I have collected several values.

I would like to calculate the mean, SD, min and max for each day. I've included a picture of a mockup, to illustrate the problem.

Does anyone have a solution? I've managed to calculate the average for each day, but only because there's an AVERAGEIFS function. Unfortunately there doesn't exist an IFS function for the other parameters.

I've tried to make a vba command, but I'm really a newbie at it. Help is much appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: Would filters work for you?

Comment: Consider using a Pivot Table.

Comment: Hmm I don't know. You would still have to a lot of manual work to make the calculations, right? All the values are already sorted by dates if that's what you're thinking?

Comment: Why do you need an IFS function for the StdDev and others? You can wrap the math on those in a regular `If` statement, no?

Comment: @BruceWayne Hmm I'm not quite sure if you can just do a regular if statement? As shown in Kfichter's example, it seems that doing a regular if statement will just calculate a value based on the entire column if one of the cells fulfill the criteria?

Comment: @Alex - ahh, you're right, I see the issue with that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use these three formulae:

```
=STDEV(IF(A:A=criteria,B:B))  'confirmed with ctrl+shift+enter
=MIN(IF(A:A=criteria,B:B))    'confirmed with ctrl+shift+enter
=MAX(IF(A:A=criteria,B:B))    'confirmed with ctrl+shift+enter
```

where criteria is the date cell specified, such as E9

These are basically STDEVIF, MINIF, MAXIF replacements as these do not exist on their own.

Comment: Hey KFichter, I'm afraid it doesn't quite work. It only seems to calculate the total standard deviation if one of the cells contains the value, unless I've misunderstood something? http://imgur.com/Fw3D2Hg

Comment: @Alex - you need to enter the formula as an array, so instead of entering the formula and hitting `Enter` or `Tab` (or just clicking elsewhere), press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` to do so.  I did and it works for me.

Comment: OMG that is so smart, I didn't knew the ctrl+shift+enter function would enter it as an array that is so smart!!! thank you so much for the help!